# Converting Sql leftjoin query to Laravel format

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

My query is giving right result in MySQL, Now I need to convert in laravel query.
My current query is:

```
SELECT menu_choices.*
FROM menu_choices
LEFT JOIN menus
ON menus.id=menu_choices.menu_id WHERE menus.restaurant_id=1
ORDER BY menus.menu_name;
```

And in laravel I am doing it like this:

```
MenuChoice::select('name')->leftJoin('menus','menus.id','=','menu_choices.menu_id')
        ->where('menus.restaurant_id',1)
        ->orderBy('menus.menu_name')
        ->get();
```

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#joins

Comment: Check the `Advanced Join Clauses` section in the link @PaulSpiegel posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query in laravel will be like this:

```
MenuChoice::leftJoin('menus','menus.id','=','menu_choices.menu_id')
        ->select('menu_choices.*')
        ->where('menus.restaurant_id',1)
        ->orderBy('menus.menu_name')
        ->get();
```

Also you can more learn about laravel queries using joins from here:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#joins

Thanks

Comment: Sorry I am not able to vote up because my reputation is below 15 :(